# How to reuse struct keys on golang?

Tags: go

Is there a way to use the keys from a struct into another struct?

For example I have the following struct:

```
type Player struct {
    Age       uint8      `json:"age"`
    Name      string     `json:"name"`
    UUID      string     `json:"uuid"`
}

type PlayerDynamo struct {
    // I want all the keys from Player at the same level as `Salary`.
    // Age       uint8      `json:"age"`
    // Name      string     `json:"name"`
    // UUID      string     `json:"uuid"`
    Salary float32 `json:"salary"`
}
```

How could I declare `PlayerDynamo` to use the same keys as `Player` ?

Answer (score 7):

Go supports a somewhat unique feature called "struct embedding" or just "embedding", a type of first-class composition (vs what most OOP languages offer, first-class inheritance).

Embedding allows you to embed one struct within another, such that the members of the embedded struct can be referenced as though they were declared on the parent structure:

```
type Player struct {
    Age       uint8      `json:"age"`
    Name      string     `json:"name"`
    UUID      string     `json:"uuid"`
}

type PlayerDynamo struct {
    Player // PlayerDynamo "embeds" Player
    Salary float32 `json:"salary"`
}
```

An instance of a `PlayerDynamo` now has both a `Player` member...

```
p := PlayerDynamo{}
p.Player.Name
```

*and* the embedded fields of `Player`:

```
p := PlayerDynamo{}
p.Name // Equivalent to p.Player.Name
```

Even methods of `Player` can be invoked on a `PlayerDynamo`:

```
func (p Player) String() string {
  return fmt.Sprintf("Player %q", p.Name)
}

p := PlayerDynamo{
  Player: Player {
    Name: "Bob",
  },
}

fmt.Println(p.String()) // Player "Bob"
```

This isn't *exactly* the same as copying the `Age`/`Name`/`UUID` fields into the `PlayerDynamo`: When you declare a new `PlayerDynamo`, you still need to initialize the embedded `Player` explicitly:

```
p := PlayerDynamo {
  Player: Player {
    Name: "test",
    Age: 45,
  }
  Salary: 42
}
```

Critically, the struct tags are copied over and marshalling to JSON works as expected, with all of the `Player` fields appearing within the marshalled representation of a `PlayerDynamo`.

See https://play.golang.org/p/6HMrlVZzIsn for a live example.

Answer (score 0):

Use embedding:

```
type PlayerDynamo struct {
   Player
   Salary float32 `json:"salary"`
}
```